# One hyperref per acronym per page

Tags: hyperref, acronyms

Currently, I'm using the `acronym` package to keep my thesis clear and understandable, because it is quite heavy on the use of acronyms in some parts. Because of this, some pages have so many acronyms, that they more or less look like someone went haywire with a blue text coloring tool.

So my question is: is it possible for either the `acronym` package, or the `hyperref` package, to only use one hyperref per acronym per page? So if one encounters an acronym for the first time on a page, he will be able to click on it and taken to the acronym definition list. The rest of the same acronyms on the same page will be printed without link.

I do not know if it is even possible for `LaTeX` to have this kind of 'reflection' on pages and links while compiling the document. Searching on this provided no results, which is why I'm resorting to the gurus over here.

Comment: Alternatively, you could hide the links with `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`, or set them up to be much less obtrusive.

Comment: I use the `classicthesis` package, and really like the aesthetics of that package as a whole. So I would rather not hide the links. Making them less obtrusive is a possibility, but I think it would still be distracting when looking at the entire page. Though, any tips on that last one would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to achieve what you want with the `acronym` package, but here's a solution that uses [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries). In order to get it as close as possible to the `acronym` package, I've used the `shortcuts`, `nonumberlist`, `nogroupskip` and `nopostdot` package options and used new commands introduced in `glossaries` version 4.04 that allow you to create the list of acronyms without the need to use `makeindex` or `xindy`. You just need to use `pdflatex` twice to make the list of acronyms appear.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage
 [
   acronyms,% create list of acronyms
   nohypertypes={acronym},% disable automated hyperlinks
   shortcuts,% enable acronym-like commands
   nonumberlist,% suppress location list
   nogroupskip,% suppress gap between letter groups
   nopostdot% suppress terminating full stop after descriptions
 ]{glossaries}

% Adjust the way entries are displayed:

\newif\ifshowacrlink

\newacronymstyle{long-short-hyperlinkperpage}
{%
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
  {%
    \ifcsdef{ac@curpg@\glslabel}%
    {%
      \edef\thispage{\thepage}%
      \ifcsequal{ac@curpg@\glslabel}{thispage}%
      {% on the same page
        \showacrlinkfalse
      }%
      {% now on a new page
        \showacrlinktrue
        \csedef{ac@curpg@\glslabel}{\thepage}%
      }%
    }%
    {%
      \csedef{ac@curpg@\glslabel}{\thepage}%
      \showacrlinktrue
    }%
  }%
  {%
    % don't hyperlink on first use:
    \showacrlinkfalse
  }%
  \ifshowacrlink
    \glshyperlink[\glsgenacfmt]{\glslabel}%
  \else
    \glsgenacfmt
  \fi
}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%
}%

\setacronymstyle{long-short-hyperlinkperpage}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newacronym{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

First use: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.
Subsequent use: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.

Filler text: \lipsum[1]

Use acronyms again: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.

More filler text: \lipsum[2]

Use acronyms again: \ac{html}, \ac{xml} and have a page spanning
paragraph of filler text. \lipsum*[3] Use acronyms again: \ac{html},
\ac{xml}.

Next paragraph: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.
And again: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.

\printnoidxglossary
[
  type=acronym,% list of acronyms
  sort=def% list in order of definition
]

\end{document}
```

First page:

[image: Image of first page]

Second page:

[image: Image of second page]

Third page:

[image: Image of third page]

The only drawback with this approach is the old problem of the page number not getting updated until the page-spanning paragraph has been completed. (See [Page number is wrong at start of page](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-wrongpn).) It would require a bit of trickery with writing the page number to the aux file to fix it.

**Edit:**

I've just uploaded `glossaries` version 4.06 to CTAN. (It make take a few days to get across all the mirrors and into the TeX distributions.) This version introduces a new command (`\glsifhyper`) that can be used within the acronym style to determine if the starred or non-starred version of commands like `\ac` was used. This means you can force off the hyperlink for individual entries (although you might want to wait until the final version of your document before you make such manual adjustments).

Updated MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage
 [
   acronyms,% create list of acronyms
   nohypertypes={acronym},% disable automated hyperlinks
   shortcuts,% enable acronym-like commands
   nonumberlist,% suppress location list
   nogroupskip,% suppress gap between letter groups
   nopostdot% suppress terminating full stop after descriptions
 ]{glossaries}

% Adjust the way entries are displayed:

\newif\ifshowacrlink

\newacronymstyle{long-short-hyperlinkperpage}
{%
  \glsifhyper
  {% unstarred version used
    \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
    {%
      \ifcsdef{ac@curpg@\glslabel}%
      {%
        \edef\thispage{\thepage}%
        \ifcsequal{ac@curpg@\glslabel}{thispage}%
        {% on the same page
          \showacrlinkfalse
        }%
        {% now on a new page
          \showacrlinktrue
          \csedef{ac@curpg@\glslabel}{\thepage}%
        }%
      }%
      {%
        \csedef{ac@curpg@\glslabel}{\thepage}%
        \showacrlinktrue
      }%
    }%
    {%
      % don't hyperlink on first use:
      \showacrlinkfalse
    }%
  }%
  {% starred version has been used so switch off the link:
     \showacrlinkfalse
  }%
  \ifshowacrlink
    \glshyperlink[\glsgenacfmt]{\glslabel}%
  \else
    \glsgenacfmt
  \fi
}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%
}%

\setacronymstyle{long-short-hyperlinkperpage}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newacronym{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

First use: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.
Subsequent use: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.

Filler text: \lipsum[1]

Use acronyms again: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.

More filler text: \lipsum[2]

Use acronyms again: \ac{html}, \ac{xml} and have a page spanning
paragraph of filler text. \lipsum*[3] Use acronyms again: \ac{html},
\ac{xml}.

Next paragraph: \ac{html}.
Suppress the link on this one: \ac*{xml}.
And again: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.

\printnoidxglossary
[
  style=tree,%
  type=acronym,% list of acronyms
  sort=def% list in order of definition
]

\end{document}
```

The second page looks like:

[image: Image of second page]

**Update:**

Here's a solution using [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) (at least v1.08). It's slightly different from the above in that it has a hyperlink on first use, whereas with the above examples the first hyperlink is the first subsequent use. (The problem with the page-spanning paragraph is still present.) The `glossaries-extra` package automatically implements the `nopostdot` option, so I've omitted it from the option list.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage
[
   acronyms,% create list of acronyms
   shortcuts,% enable acronym-like commands
   nogroupskip% suppress gap between letter groups
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrEnableEntryUnitCounting{acronym}{0}{page}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newacronym{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}

\renewcommand*{\glslinkcheckfirsthyperhook}{%
  \ifnum\glsentrycurrcount\glslabel>0
   \setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample Chapter}

First use: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.
Subsequent use: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.

Filler text: \lipsum[1]

Use acronyms again: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.

More filler text: \lipsum[2]

Use acronyms again: \ac{html}, \ac{xml} and have a page spanning
paragraph of filler text. \lipsum*[3] Use acronyms again: \ac{html},
\ac{xml}.

Next paragraph: \ac{html}.
Suppress the link on this one: \ac*{xml}.
And again: \ac{html}, \ac{xml}.

\printunsrtglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

This uses the entry-counting mechanism to switch off the hyperlink. It also uses a new command `\printunsrtglossary` rather than the `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossary` combination. The `\printunsrtglossary` command is the closest match to the `acronym` package as it doesn't sort or produce a location list, but simply lists the terms in the order of definition. This means you only need to use `pdflatex` *once* to make the list appear.

Start of first page:

[image: image of top of first page]

Second page:

[image: image of second page]

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer. Your standalone example works, but when I try to apply it on my own framework, it fails. Everything works, until I use an acronym using `\ac`. As long as I don't have a used acronym, the document compiles. When I do use an acronym, the compiler stops at `\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,sort=def]`, i.e. it cannot create the list of acronyms. This is probably due to the classicthesis framework and some other conflicting package, but unfortunately I cannot figure out which one.

Comment: @Kazu The default glossary style (`list`, which uses the `description` environment) seems to conflict with `classicthesis`. Try `\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,sort=def,style=tree]`

Comment: That indeed seems to be the problem. I'm sure I can restyle the tree structure such that it matches the aesthetics of `classicthesis`. One side-note before I can mark your answer as a solution: on some pages still two identical acronyms have links. Could this be due to floating figures, where your code thinks a pagebreak is made even though because of an earlier figure this is not the case?

Comment: @Kazu That's probably the case. I was going to suggest you use the starred version `\ac*` to manually suppress the link if this situation occurs, but I realised the starred version no longer works with the new acronym style I defined in my example. I'll see if I can find a way of fixing it.

Comment: I just noticed that it actually is an inversion of the page-spanning paragraph problem you mentioned. If you would assume the page-spanning paragraph belongs to the previous page, it would be the first occurrence, and therefore be a link. I guess I will take that problem for granted, and use your solution altogether. (Though your fix for the starred version would be great!)