# Clickable Acronym

Tags: acronyms

Not sure how to say "Clickable" maybe `hyperref`?

I'm using the acronym package `\usepackage{acronym}` in my thesis.

And at the beginning I, adding the list of acronyms as:

```
\chapter*{Acrónimos}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acrónimos}
\input{acronimos.tex}
```

Each acronym is defined in the `acronimos.tex` file like:

```
\acrodef{SNC}{Sistema Nervioso Central}
SNC: Sistema Nervioso Central.

\acrodef{TENS}{Transcutaneous electrical nerve stimulation por sus siglas en inglés}
TENS: Spinal Cord Injury.
```

And calling each acronym in the text as

```
... parapleja es causada por \ac{SCI}, las señales  ...
```

I'd like to know if is possible that the acronym in the pdf could be clickable and it goes to its definition in the acronyms list? Just like `\cite{source}` does.

Is it possible?

And a seccond question, why my latex doesn't complete the acronyms? not even if I write the command `\a` + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> it doesn't find the `\ac{}` command only shows `\acute{}`. It doesn't autocomplete `\ac{}` but it compiles ok.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX! For the second question, as that is actually completely unrelated, it is better if you post a separate question about it. Note that auto-completion like that is a feature of whatever text-editor you use (you don't say which), so that editor hasn't implemented/activated auto-completion of macros from the `acronym` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glossaries` package instead. See the answer in this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164936/one-hyperref-per-acronym-per-page).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution without the `glossaries` package.

However, note that this is probably not the best solution and might have some side effects (not tested), but it works in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\acrotarget}[1]{\hypertarget{#1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\aclink}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{\ac{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Acronyms}
\acrodef{FA}{First Acronym}
\acrotarget{FA}: First Acronym.

\acrodef{SA}{Second Acronym}
\acrotarget{SA}: Second Acronym.

\newpage % Only to see if it is really clickable

\section*{Body}

Here I call the \aclink{FA}, \aclink{FA} again, and \aclink{SA}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :D I tried, it makes my acronym clickable but when I click on it, the hyperref goes to the first document page instead to the acronyms list.

Body:
La paraplejia es una enfermedad en la cual la \aclink{FES} tiene aplicación tanto terapéutica ... 

acronyms.tex:
\acrodef{FES}{Functional Electric Stimulation por sus siglas en inglés}
\acrotarget{FES}: Functional Electric Stimulation.

Thanks :)

Comment: @EinSoldiatGott Thanks, I messed up the arguments in the command `\aclink`. I corrected my answer, that should now really work.